# Squid works but doesn't give the page

Tags: squid

I have a **squid (v4.8)** installed on a virtual machine, let's call it **router**, this machine can connect with both the Internet and an internal network which leads to another virtual machine, **storage**.

I want **squid** to:

- work as a cache proxy, and
- work in both forward and transparent mode.

I haven't read anybody who have done the same, but I've seen some squid configurations where more than one port is specified to listen, and at least one of them can have the **intercept** switch. I have to say I also have another interface (*host-only*) which connects **router** to **host** (the actual machine), this interface is only to test some features.

facts:

1. With a web browser from **host**:

   - I'm asked to type the credentials
   - If I type wrong credentials I'm asked again
   - If I type the right one It goes on

     - If I try to go to a webpage which is not on the whitelist I see the squid banner
     - If I try to go to an allowed webpage... it just keeps loading without showing anything
2. With a command line application from within **storage**:

   - If I try to retrieve a *blackpage* (not on whitelist) I get:

     - An HTML webpage with **ERR_ACCESS_DENIED** (`curl <webpage> -o <file>`)
     - A text file with **ERROR 403: Forbidden** (`wget <webpage> -o <file>`)
     - In both cases I get from `access.log`: **TCP_DENIED/403 *size* GET http://*blackurl* - HIER_NONE/-** and in `cache.log`: **NOTICE: Authentication not applicable on intercepted requests.**
   - If I try to retrieve a *whitepage* (on whitelist) It keeps "loading".
     When I quit (`^C`) I see from `access.log`: **NONE_ABORTED/000 0 GET http://*whiteurl* - HIER_NONE/- -** and nothing at all in `cache.log`.
   - Issuing `curl -x "http://user:pass@domain:8080" <url>`:

     - If the credentials are incorrect I get an HTML file with an **ERR_CACHE_ACCESS_DENIED**.
       File `access.log`: **TCP_DENIED/407 *size* GET http://*url* *user* HIER_NONE/- text/html** and nothing on `cache.log`.
     - If the credentials are correct:

       - A blacklist page: I actually get it.
         File `access.log`: **TCP_MISS/200 *size* GET http://*blackurl* *user* HIER_DIRECT/*ipurl*** (Or **TCP_REFRESH_MODIFIED**) and nothing in `cache.log`
       - A whitelist page: I don't manage to fetch anything and when I abort I get on `access.log`: **TCP_MISS_ABORTED/000 0 GET http://*whiteurl* - HIER_NONE/- -**, nothing in `cache.log`.
       - NOTE: I've mistakenly tried to fetch a page which led me to a redirection, so I got **301 Moved Permanently**. File `access.log`: **TCP_MISS/301 *size* GET http://*whitepage* - HIER_DIRECT/*ipurl*** and nothing in `cache.log`.
       - NOTE: The previous page was in my *whitelist*.
       - NOTE: If I asked for a forbidden page with credentials it always appears at the end of the url.

My squid config file (`/etc/squid/squid.conf`):

```
http_port 8080
http_port 3128 intercept
dns_nameservers 127.0.0.1 1.1.1.1 # Sometimes squid doesn't load the nameserver from /etc/resolv.conf
# Storage
cache_dir ufs /var/cache/squid 3000 16 256
maximum_object_size 250 MB
refresh_pattern -i ".+\.(mp4|mkv|webm|iso)$" 0 20% 2880
# Authentication
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/basic_db_auth \
  --user "user" --password "pass" \
  --table "table" --usercol "userinsomelang" --passwdcol "passinsomelang" --md5 \
  --persist
auth_param basic children 10
auth_param basic realm "Squid proxy"
auth_param basic credentialsttl 1 hour
auth param basic casesensitive on
# ACL lists
acl whitedomain srcdomain .mydomain.com
acl whitehosts src "/etc/squid/files/whitehosts.list"
acl whitesites dstdomain "/etc/squid/files/whitesites.list"
acl blocksites dstdomain "/etc/squid/files/blacksites.list"
acl blockurl url_regex -i "/etc/squid/files/block_url.list"
acl worktime time M-F 8:00-17:00
acl worktime time HF 18:00-23:00
acl safeports port 80
acl safeports port 443
acl safeports port 1025-65535
acl db_auth proxy_auth REQUIRED
acl CONNECT method CONNECT  # I have no idea what this is for
# Actions
http_access deny blockurl
http_access allow whitesites
http_access allow wortime
http_access deny !safeports
http_access allow db_auth whitehosts
http_access deny all
```

I think my `iptables` configuration in **router** is not needed, you can figure out it works well with those logs. And I'm using the bare minimum to check it wasn't because of it.

I also have done some packet sniffing, I can see packages coming from the internal network, packages going out and coming in from my external NIC (name resolution related with the pages asked) and that's it.

So I see two main problems, there may be more:

1. I can't fetch whitelist pages (transparent or forward mode).
2. I can fetch blacklist pages with the right credentials but only from the command line, I can't achieve this with my web browser.

How can I fix this? Why is it working like this?